# Hard refresh the page every time when I update the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, .net-core, babeljs

Whenever I update the code on production the changes can't reflect without hard refreshing (ctrl+F5) the page. So, Is there any way by coding I can handle this problem because the end user doesn't know these things.
Pls suggest. Currently, I am developing using the Dot net core for API's and reactJS as frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement PWA, whenever a new version/file is available it automatically downloads. In PWA you can add an alert like "App Update is available" Here is the reference for ReactJs: https://dev.to/daniellycosta/showing-new-version-available-notification-on-create-react-app-pwas-3jc9